# Github uploading file count limit

Tags: file, github, upload, uploading

This is a simple question.

**Is there a way to increase github uploading file count in web ui?**

Currently github limit uploading more than 100 at a time.
So it is hard to upload a folder containing 100+ files. Even files are tiny like icons, this limit applies.

I was expecting that github will be more sophisticated.

Comment: If anyone knows any answer, please reply.

Comment: The big question would be: "Why?" Normally you create a repo, then just push to it with `git`.

Comment: But I have a folders that used entirely locally. Like django project with static folder containing 100+ icons is a common thing. Which I like to upload to github.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such way to bypass the web UI limit.  In general, the web UI is designed for very small, quick edits, and is not intended to be a substitute for committing things using Git and a clone of the repository.

If you want to add lots of files, you can clone the repository with `git clone`, then change into the clone, copy the files where you want them, and do `git add` with the new files.  Once you're done, you can use `git push` to push your changes up into the GitHub repository.